What algorithm can solve linear inequalities when dealing with matrices?
I naively assumed that the following inequality can be solved by taking a matrix inverse, wherein A is a matrix and, x and b are vectors -
$Ax≥b⟺Ax=b+z,z≥0⟺x=A^{−1}b+A^{−1}z,z≥0$
$ z_i = (Ax)_i - b_i, \, \forall i $
However, I found out that this technique won't work. Consider the following example that someone showed me on Math Discord -
$\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & -3 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\ 
y 
\end{pmatrix} > 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ 
6 
\end{pmatrix}$
isn't the same as
$\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y 
\end{pmatrix} > 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 
0 & -\frac{1}{3} 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
4 \\ 
6 
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 \\ 
-2 
\end{pmatrix}
$
Could someone tell me why this happens? Also, what algorithm/technique could I use to solve the inequality and get the vector x.
Edit -
My apologies for the bad notation. Thanks @River Li for suggesting changes.Please let me know if I can make more changes to improve the question.
Based on the comments, the reason the inequality doesn't hold is that the matrix may have negative elements. What if the matrix was a non-negative matrix? Would the inequality hold?

What is your ordering on your vector space? There is no norm which induces a total order

@Malady Who says that a purported total order should be induced by a norm (and what does that even mean)? Here $v\ge w$ means $[\forall j, v_j\ge w_j]$, i.e. $\Bbb R^n$ has the product partial order.

@SassatelliGiulio I was just asking what order we were using. It was not at all clear from the question. If the OP wanted a total order (which I could not tell from the question), there isn’t one which behaves nicely with the vector space structure.

@Malady I am not familiar with the concept of vector order. Do I need to understand it to solve my question?

The question is, what do you mean by $X \ge Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ are vectors?

@desert_ranger Usually, you may use uppercase for matrices and lowercase for vectors. How about $Ax \ge b \iff Ax = b + z, z \ge 0 \iff x = A^{-1}b + A^{-1}z, z \ge 0$ (assume that $A$ has an inverse)?

@RobertIsrael I agree with Malady. "Here v≥w means [∀j,vj≥wj]" In fact, I don't even see (based on my limited LA background, how it can be interpreted differently".

@RiverLi Thank you for your comment. I apologize, but I don't understand. Are you suggesting I should rewrite my question with vectors in lowercase? I could definitely do that. Also, I am not sure from where did $z$ come from?

"why this happens": even in dimension one, $(-2)x \ge 4$ does not imply $x \ge -2$

@desert_ranger Yes, It is a notation convention. How about: $z_i = (Ax)_i - b_i, \forall i$?

Assuming $X \ge Y$ means $X_i \ge Y_i$ for all $i$, the solutions $X$ of $A X \ge B$ (where $A$ is an $m \times n$ real matrix and $B \in \mathbb R^m$) form a (possibly empty, possibly unbounded) closed convex polyhedron in $\mathbb R^n$ with up to $m$ faces.  These faces are on the hyperplanes
$A_i X = B_i$ where $A_i$ are the rows of $A$.  I'm not sure what you mean by "solve" in this context, but linear programming is the way to answer most questions about this polyhedron.

Thank you for your answer. By "solve", I am looking for a vector x that ensures that the inequality holds.

OK, so use your favourite linear programming software with an objective of $0$.
