How do I solve inequalities concerning matrices using linear programming
I would like to solve the inequality,
$$Ax≥b⟺Ax=b+z,z≥0⟺x=A^{−1}b+A^{−1}z,z≥0$$
$$ z_i = (Ax)_i - b_i, \, \forall i $$, here $A$ is a matrix and $x$ and $b$ are vectors.
Here is a minimal problem that I would like to solve -
$\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & -3 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\ 
y 
\end{pmatrix} \geq 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ 
6 
\end{pmatrix}$
Please let me know if something is unclear in my question.
Regarding my prerequisite knowledge, I have a Master's in Engineering. During that time, I did touch on some linear programming concepts like Simplex. Unfortunately, I don't remember much about it.

What does it mean to be greater than $\begin{pmatrix}
4 \
6
\end{pmatrix}$?

@ZubinMukerjee It means that $x \geq 4$ and $y \geq 6$. Please let me know if you need more clarification.

You have no inequalities between vectors, you could only compare there length. if you compare the components it just gives you  for example 2x>4  This does not seem a problem?

I did not know that there are no inequalities between vectors. Thank you for the information.
Yes, I understand that comparing components will lead to scalar equations. Would there be a problem doing that? Can't these scalar equations once again be placed back in Matrix form?

Componentwise inequality as you've described does make sense, and is usually denoted by $\prec$ and $\preceq$. See this answer for discussion of the notation: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/669089

@ZubinMukerjee Thank you for your answer. However, I find that with your answer, I won't be able to combine my results, back into a matrix. I asked a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4919278/what-algorithm-can-solve-linear-inequalities-when-dealing-with-matrices and was asked to use linear programming.

Why do you want to combine your results back into a matrix? What is the original problem you are working on? What is the goal? You can combine them back into a componentwise inequality if you want - this is only notation, as it means the same thing as: $x \geq 2$ and $-y \geq 2$. I've added that to the answer. Remember to flip inequalities when multiplying/dividing by negative constants

@ZubinMukerjee Thank you for your edit. The reason I want to combine the results back into a matrix is because computing $\begin{pmatrix}
x \
y
\end{pmatrix}$ is only a part of my algorithm. I need to process it further. Additionally, I also need an algorithmic way to perform the computation shown in your answer.

Assuming you are referring to componentwise inequality, usually denoted by $\preceq$, you can multiply:
$$\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & -3 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\ 
y 
\end{pmatrix} &\succeq
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ 
6 
\end{pmatrix}\\\\
\begin{pmatrix} 
2x \\ 
-3y 
\end{pmatrix} &\succeq 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ 
6 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$
So,
$$2x \geq 4 \qquad \implies \quad x \geq 2$$
$$-3y \geq 6 \qquad \implies \quad y \leq -2\\$$
Notice that the inequality in the last line is flipped!

If you prefer, you can write the final inequalities as:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\ 
-y 
\end{pmatrix} \succeq 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\ 
2 
\end{pmatrix}$$
